# PostgreSQL Database search for city name in name column and print all record of selected city name

Tags: java, database, postgresql

i am trying to enter the city name if city name is exist in database (else error message), then i want to print selected city name, population, latitude and longitude. Rest of the code is working well.

[Database image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFicW.png)

```
public static void city(){
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Scanner k = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the name");
        String Name = k.nextLine ();

        try {
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM cities WHERE name ="+Name);
            // At least a record selected
            if(rs.isBeforeFirst ()){
                //Iterates through each record
                while (rs.next ()){
                    String name = rs.getString (i:1);
                    int population = rs.getInt(i:2);
                    double latitude = rs.getDouble (i:3);
                    double longitude = rs.getDouble(i:4);


                    System.out.println("Name: " + name);
                    System.out.println("Population: " + population);
                    System.out.println("Latitude: " + latitude);
                    System.out.println("Longitude: " + longitude);
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("No records selected.");
            }
        }

        catch(SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error selecting from table: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            try {
                rs.close();                                                                                             
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                //ResultSet still null/nothing to close
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Don't concatenate values into a SQL string. Please use a `PreparedStatement` https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/ - then your problem will go away automagically.

Answer (score 0):

First if field "name" is character varying or text, you must modify your 8th line like this:

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM cities WHERE name ='"+Name+"'");
```

Comment: Error selecting from table: The column index is out of range: 2, number of columns: 1. it does not work.

Comment: String name = rs.getString (1);
                    int population = rs.getInt(2);
                    double latitude = rs.getDouble (3);
                    double longitude = rs.getDouble(4);

Answer (score 0):

This will check whether there is city name in your database

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM cities WHERE name = '"+name+"'");
if(rs.next()){
   //it exist
   //print record
}
else{
   //it does not exist
   System.out.println("Error Message!");
}
```

You can also use `PreparedStatement` for your query instead of the above query.

```
PreparedStatement p = yourConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM cities WHERE name = ?");
p.setString(1, name);
rs = p.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Error selecting from table: The column index is out of range: 2, number of columns: 1. it does not work.

Comment: Try to use this : `String name = rs.getString ("name"); int population = rs.getInt("population"); double latitude = rs.getDouble ("latitude"); double longitude = rs.getDouble("longitude");`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's missing quotes, try this:

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM cities WHERE name = '"+Name+"' ");
```

Comment: Error selecting from table: The column index is out of range: 2, number of columns: 1.